# How to extract and read numbers from a text file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

Suppose the text file (say, x.txt) is

```
= 0
< 1
= 2
```

I want the output to be `[0, 1, 2]` and `['=', '<', '=']`. How can I achieve this in python3?

Comment: open the file, read the file, split each line, store first and second elements in different lists

Comment: `with open('x.txt', 'r') as f:d = f.read().split();ops = d[0::2];nums = list(map(int, d[1::2]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's open method to read the file

First, make 2 lists

```
nums = []
ops = []
```

Then, use the open method to read file and loop through the lines in the file while adding the operators and numbers to the list.

```
file = open(“x.txt”, “r”) 
for line in file:
    line = line.split()
    ops.append(line[0])
    nums.append(line[1])
```

Then print if wanted.

```
print(ops, nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[]
b=[]
with open("x.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        a.append(line.split()[0])
        b.append(line.split()[1])
print (a)
print (b)
```

Comment: Haha sorry...I guess im so used to autocomplete on Pycharm :)

Answer (score 0):

Very straight forward. Just make empty lists, iterate over lines in file using `with open` and readlines method. Append to the lists. Cheers.

```
#init lists 
nums = [] 
operators = []

#open file, iterate over lines, append values 
with open('x.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        _line = line.split()
        nums.append(_line[1])
        operators.append(_line[0])
```